# Error in compiling 4.4.4 KitKat (gralloc)

Tags: android, c++, android-4.4-kitkat

I got this error -

```
frameworks/native/libs/gui/Surface.cpp: In member function 'virtual android::status_t android::Surface::lock(ANativeWindow_Buffer*, ARect*)':
frameworks/native/libs/gui/Surface.cpp:828:29: error: 'GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_INTERNAL_ONLY' was not declared in this scope
target thumb C++: libprotobuf-cpp-2.3.0-lite <= external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/repeated_field.cc
make: *** [/home/aniket/candykat-kk/out/target/product/cancro/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libgui_intermediates/Surface.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc: In function 'void google::protobuf::ShutdownProtobufLibrary()':
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:355:58: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
```

I don't know what to do,searched Google but couldn't find any relevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the variable is not declared in the proper scope... check line 828 and see if within that scope GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_INTERNAL_ONLY exists. Watch out for other blocks, which are parts of code within {}. If it is declared in some inner block, and used outside that block, then it no longer exists. You should declare it so that it exists in the proper scope.

Comment: What I can see here is - #ifdef QCOM_BSP
        setUsage(mReqUsage & GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_EXTERNAL_ONLY |
                mReqUsage & GRALLOC_USAGE_PRIVATE_INTERNAL_ONLY |
                    GRALLOC_USAGE_SW_READ_OFTEN |
                    GRALLOC_USAGE_SW_WRITE_OFTEN);
#else
      setUsage(GRALLOC_USAGE_SW_READ_OFTEN | GRALLOC_USAGE_SW_WRITE_OFTEN);
#endif
    }

Comment: It is in proper scope,still not compiling.